# Taylor Series expansion and first four terms of $7x^2 e^{-4x}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

As the series I got

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(4x)^n/n!
$$

which I think is right.

However, I am not sure how to get the first four non zero terms.

Comment: Trying to fix formatting...

Comment: Put double dollar signs around your LaTeX, like `$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} $$`, to make it show up on a separate line.  I've gone ahead and fixed it for you this time :)  Also, you might want to have a read of [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$7x^2 e^{-4x}=7x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-4x)^n}{n!}=7\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-4)^n}{n!}x^{n+2}=7\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-4)^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}x^{n}$$

Comment: So now just set $n=2$ and this gives you first non-zero term. Setting $n=3$ gives you second non-zero term, etc.